# TableViewer shrinks to a single row with a scroll bar when new input is set

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface, tableviewer

I am implementing a plug-in in eclipse, which reads a set of values from a database and displays it in a `TableViewer` inside a `ViewPart`. The TableViewer uses an `ArrayContentProvider` as shown

```
viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
...
viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
```

I also have a handler which has access to the `TableViewer` instance for importing data from an XML file. When the importer imports data, I create a `ModelProvider` instance which generates a list of objects whose data is displayed by `TableViewer`.

The handler then sets the input:

`viewer.setInput(new ModelProvider(Data.getDocs()).getTableRows())`;

When I test this application, with this `ViewPart` already open (and the `TableViewer` being empty) and invoke the handler for importing data, the data is imported succesfully but the `TableViewer` shows only a single row and the scroll bar. Only when I drag the `ViewPart` to some other location on the Workbench, then all the rows are shown.

I have even tried:

```
viewer.setInput(new ModelProvider(Data.getDocs()).getTableRows());
viewer.refresh();
```

and

```
viewer.setInput(null);
viewer.setInput(new ModelProvider(Data.getDocs()).getTableRows());
viewer.refresh();
```

but nothing works. How do I make all the rows display as soon as new input is set?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what layout settings did you use to get your table to show up with exactly one row?

Comment: @Neil I don't have the code with me, it was a corporate project I was working on as a part of my internship. And I don't remember the exact details either. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have a table problem, but a layout problem.

If your viewer's parent has a `GridLayout`, then do:

`viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));`

OR you can just set a `FillLayout` on the parent, and that's it.

(if you think I misunderstood your question, please post a screenshot)

Comment: `viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));`  worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: @saqibns Cool! I recommend [this article on SWT layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Cheers!