# JFace TableViewer - How to set the size to display one row only?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a TableViewer which I know will always have one row of data in it.
When I have data for that table, I can call `setInputData(...)` and pass the one object with `Arrays.asList(...)` to have the Table sized correctly displaying the one row of data.

When I do not have the object, I still want the Table to be sized to display only one row. However, if I use this: `setInputData(new ArrayList<Object>(0))`, the Table is auto-sized to show around 3 & a half blank rows. How can I get the Table to always be sized to display only one row?

I should mention that I'm using GridLayout for the Composite that the TableViewer is within as well as for the TableViewer.

I have tried setting the bounds for the SWT Table within the TableViewer to be the size of a single item, but that hasn't helped. I haven't found any similar questions on SO or through a general Google search, however in this question: [TableViewer shrinks to a single row with a scroll bar when new input is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345882/tableviewer-shrinks-to-a-single-row-with-a-scroll-bar-when-new-input-is-set), the asker was able to have his Table sized to show one row. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep. to comment asking him how he did that.

**EDIT:** Adding some more relevant code

```
final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parentComposite, SWT.V_SCROLL);
scrolledComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
scrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(scrolledComposite, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
// I'm setting the LabelProvider, ContentProvider here.
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.heightHint = tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight();
tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(gridData);

scrolledComposite.setContent(tableViewer.getControl());
scrolledComposite.setMinSize(tableViewer.getTable().getGridLineWidth(), tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight());
```

And then, in a separate method:

`tableViewer.setInputData(objectList); // This may be empty or have exactly one object`

Comment: If it is working when you have one item in the table it sounds like it would be simplest just to put one dummy item in the table when it is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the place where I set the input to the table, I do not know the type of the object. It gets passed down. So I cannot instantiate a new object of the correct type because I do not know the type at the time & I cannot give a generic `new Object()` because then I get errors when the `LabelProvider` tries to map the new object.

Comment: Why is the table embedded in a `ScrolledComposite`? It has its own scrollbars, there is no need for a `ScrolledComposite`.

Comment: Its inside that because I'm mimicking the scroll bar visibility of another table for consistency of looks. And since we cannot always dictate when the scroll bar is enabled, I'm doing that part through a `ScrolledComposite`

Comment: The `ScrolledComposite` is likely to cause the behavior that you see. I'd rather try to manually show the table scrollbars if this is really desirable. e.g. `table.getVerticalBar().setVisible( true )`. You may need to forcibly show the scrollbars on resize (and maybe other events). But all that sounds like 'brushing against the grain' to me.

Comment: I realize that it all sounds like a very hacked-together solution. But considering the existing codebase and the asks, I'm left with very limited options. So, `table.getVerticalBar().setVisible(true)` I've tried that. But apparently, the OS decides whether to show the scroll bar or not. It cannot always be guaranteed programatically. Which is why I went to a `ScrolledComposite` since that ensures a scroll bar to be displayed when I need one, whether it's truly required or not.

Comment: @greg-449 @RüdigerHerrmann - I managed to get the correct height by putting the `TableViewer` inside a `Composite` which is inside the `ScrolledComposite`. Then I did a `setContent` of the Composite on the `ScrolledComposite`. After setting both to `FillLayout` & setting the size of the `ScrolledComposite`, I was able to get the correct height. But unfortunately, the length was not getting aligned to the size of the Composite so I just dropped that idea & used `java.lang.reflect` to figure out the type of Object at runtime & create a blank object to get a single row sized `TableViewer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone arriving at this link looking for a solution, building off of Rüdiger Herrmann's answer, what finally worked for me was to create the `TableViewer` inside a `Composite` which is then placed inside the `ScrolledComposite`. (This was found through another StackOverflow link which stated that a `Control` needs to be placed inside a `Composite` within the `ScrolledComposite` for it to show up correctly.) Then the `Composite` needs to be set to the `ScrolledComposite` like: `ScrolledComposite.setContent(Composite)`.

After setting both, the `ScrolledComposite` & the `Composite` Layouts to `FillLayout` & setting the size of the `ScrolledComposite` to be `tableViewer.getTable().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight())`, I was able to get the correct height for the `TableViewer`.

Once that's done, after `tableViewer.setInput(objectList);` is called, I set the size to the `TableViewer` with: `tableViewer.getTable().setSize(tableViewer.getTable().computeSize(tableViewer.getTable().getClientArea().width, tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight()));`

Answer (score 2):

You can query the table to compute its size for one row like this

```
Point Site = table.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, table.getItemHeight() * 1 );
```

Next you need to tell the layout to reserve that much space for the table. In a `GridLayout`, for example, use `gridData.heightHint`

Comment: So here's what I tried, after creating the TableViewer:
`GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.heightHint = tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight();
tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(gridData);`
That didn't seem to help, the table's still auto-sizing to show three & a half blank lines.

Comment: Possibly the layout of a parent or a sibling of the table causes the table to ignore the hint and use the (remaining?) space. Hard to tell without seeing more code. Can you provide a self-contained code snippet that shows the problem?

Comment: That's turning out a bit more complicated than I expected, I've edited the original post with some relevant code that I can pull out, let me know if it makes sense (or doesn't). Thanks.